# How do I reselect the same cell in a DGV after an edit?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Sorry if this is a trivial question, I barely started C# and programming in general.

The default behaviour seems to be to jump to the next row and cell 0. I tried it like this:

```
private void DBUpdate()
    {
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM WPVersand WHERE erledigt =''", Globals.cn);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

        System.Data.DataTable changes = dt.GetChanges();
        if (changes != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Set the current cell to the updated cell
                int row = dgvDaten.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int column = dgvDaten.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;


                DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Änderung übernehmen?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    

                    da.Update(changes);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();

                    
                    dgvDaten.CurrentCell = dgvDaten[column, row];
                    dgvDaten.Refresh();
                }
                else if (res == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    bs = new BindingSource();
                    bs.DataSource = dt;

                    dgvDaten.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                    dgvDaten.Columns.Clear();

                    dgvDaten.DataSource = bs;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dgvDaten_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {         
        bs.EndEdit();
        dgvDaten.EndEdit();
        DBUpdate();

    }
```

But that only reselects the same cell on the next row.

What am I missing here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: changes contains inserts/deletes (then remembering the row/cell index does not help) or just updates?

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow. "row" and "column" store the current cell, and the moment edit is finished, the stored values get reapplied to reselect the same cell again overiding the default behavior.

At least in theory, practically that's only happening for the column, not the row, the latter still advances.

Comment: Ok you have a single change here from editing the current cell. The change of cells will happen after that event so whatever you try in that event will happen to early. How did you force CellValueChanged? Mostly this event is executed when you leave the cell and you are trying to prevent that. Feels like an unnatural behavior to me that he shouldn't be allowed to change cells (and ending editing implicitly on the way doing it).

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that outcome is to inherit `DataGridView`, swap out the control in your Designer file with your new `DataGridViewEx` control, then change its default behavior, customizing it to do what you want which is **reselect the same cell in DGV after an edit**.

---

Here's a first pass at a custom `DataGridViewEx` that I tested and seems to do the trick. Whether or not this is the *exact* behavior you're looking for, this is how you can do it and these are the methods that have to do with row/column/cell/currentcell selection.

```
class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        _isChanging = true;
        base.OnCellValueChanged(e);
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _isChanging = false));
    }
    bool _isChanging = false;
    protected override void SetSelectedCellCore(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool selected)
    {
        if (_isChanging)
        {
            base.SetSelectedCellCore(CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, CurrentCell.RowIndex, selected);
        }
        else
        {
            base.SetSelectedCellCore(columnIndex, rowIndex, selected);
        }
    }
    protected override void SetSelectedColumnCore(int columnIndex, bool selected)
    {
        if (_isChanging)
        {
            base.SetSelectedColumnCore(CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, selected);
        }
        else
        {
            base.SetSelectedColumnCore(columnIndex, selected && !_isChanging);
        }
    }
    protected override void SetSelectedRowCore(int rowIndex, bool selected)
    {
        if (_isChanging)
        {
            base.SetSelectedRowCore(CurrentCell.RowIndex, selected);
        }
        else
        {
            base.SetSelectedRowCore(rowIndex, selected && !_isChanging);
        }
    }
    protected override bool SetCurrentCellAddressCore(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool setAnchorCellAddress, bool validateCurrentCell, bool throughMouseClick)
    {
        if (_isChanging)
        {
            return base.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, CurrentCell.RowIndex, setAnchorCellAddress, validateCurrentCell, throughMouseClick);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(columnIndex, rowIndex, setAnchorCellAddress, validateCurrentCell, throughMouseClick);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Test**

I used this minimal code to test. Since the question *is* about cell selection and *isn't* about `DataTable` bindings I chose to make a very simple `DataSource` for the DGV for testing purposes.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dgvDaten.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        dgvDaten.DataSource = Records;
        Records.Add(new Record());
        dgvDaten.Columns[nameof(Record.Guid)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dgvDaten.Columns[nameof(Record.Description)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        Records.Clear();

        Records.Add(new Record { Description = "Apple" });
        Records.Add(new Record { Description = "Orange" });
        Records.Add(new Record { Description = "Grape" });
    }

    BindingList<Record> Records = new BindingList<Record>();
}
class Record
{
    public string Guid { get; set; } = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 15).ToUpper();
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find an existing structure that looks like your class, so I added it just as a new class. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Here's the working sample you can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/data-grid-view-custom-selection.git) from my GitHub repo that can get you started. To run it, you would just open Visual Studio and use the **Clone a Repository** option using this link. Leave me another comment if it gives you any trouble.